# Matlab: reading possibly faulty .csv

Tags: matlab, csv

I'm writing GUI where I load `.csv` files containing data from measurements. The file is well defined:

```
<variable>(<unit>),<variable>(<unit>),...
0.005,NaN,...
```

and I am processing it in `Vars`, `Units` and `Data`:

```
A=importdata('foo.csv',',');
Data=A.data;
[Vars,Units]=ProcessHeaderLine(A.colheaders);
```

Problem occurs when the data part is corrupted - there is string instead of number in the cell:

```
<variable>(<unit>),<variable>(<unit>),...
0.005,"- N/A -   ",...
```

In that case it takes long time to run the `importdata` function and error is thrown:

> `Error using importdata (line 136)`
>   `Unable to open file.`
>
> `Error in <.m file> (line 384)`
>   `A=importdata('foo.csv'],',');`

Is there faster way than `try-catch` this approach with ability to process both header and data and be able to process data containig string "cells"?

Comment: MATLAB is great for handling numeric-only data files.  It is not so great with string data, and none of the MATLAB readers are going to work well with data that can change types from one record to the next.  Your example is particularly troubling since it shows unbalanced quotes!!  If your "string" data is almost always the same, and it is a marker for when real data was not available, then the best solution is to pre-process the data file. Replace the string (in this case, `" N/A`) with a numeric value that is not valid for your application (maybe `-1`?  maybe `999999`?).

Comment: @gariepy The string is `"- N/A -   "` actually, and I can identify the problem and I can repair it semi-automatically. But I am the only one here (in the lab) to be insane enough to trace it and face it. Result is intended to be foolproof sealed black box...

Comment: One of the testing files - the faulty one - contain the string in whole column. The problem is that I don't know *why* there are `N/A` flags. Regarding the function design I don't know whether looking for string in second row is enough to decide how to handle the file.

Comment: So if you know that you can get the string `"- N/A - "` under certain conditions, then pre-processing the data file to remove them adds robustness to your system, especially if you can't fix all the cases where it happens.  I've had to do this many times when running multi-step simulations where output from one sim doesn't quite match the input needed for another sim.  And adding the pre-processing step is very simple, and allows you to move on with your work if you need to, and fix the `N/A` problem later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is a MATLAB question, Perl is the best way to pre-process the file (and Perl is included with MATLAB distributions!).  The following command line script replaces the `"- N/A -"` with `999999`.  Pick any replacement value you like, and handle it in the MATLAB after you run `importdata()`.

```
perl -pi -e 's/\"- N\/A -\"/999999/g' filename.csv
```

Note: this changes the file in-place!  Make sure to make a backup copy of your file before trying this.

Note 2: you could run this pre-processing step from the GUI if you really need to, using a MATLAB `system()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is more suited towards data which is laid out vertically instead of horizontally like you have, you can use the readtable function.

```
% Use readtable to read the data as a table:
% The first row is the column names, the second row is the data
t = readtable('foo.csv', 'ReadVariableNames', false);

% Use {} brackets to extract from the table
colheaders = t{1,:};
Data = str2double(t{2,:});
```

In this case, str2double will take any invalid text, like your "- N/A -   ", and convert it to NaN.